# Wi-Fi Manager Component on ESP32 - xQueueSemaphoreTake Assertion Failure

Tags: freertos, esp-idf

I have been working on creating a Wi-Fi Manager component using the ESP32 library. However, I've been encountering an error that I haven't been able to resolve for the past three days. I'm feeling frustrated and seeking help to understand what I might be doing wrong.

I have a GitHub repository where I've shared the code for the core_wifim.c file: [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/horsemann07/auto_espnow/blob/master/components/wifi_manager/src/core_wifim.c)

In my code, I have a main function that initializes the NVS partition, turns on the Wi-Fi, and attempts to connect to a Wi-Fi network using the wifim_connect_ap function. Here's the main function:

```
void app_main(void)
{
    esp_err_t ret = ESP_FAIL;

    /* Initialize NVS partition */
    ret = nvs_flash_init();
    if (ret == ESP_ERR_NVS_NO_FREE_PAGES || ret == ESP_ERR_NVS_NEW_VERSION_FOUND)
    {
        /* NVS partition was truncated and needs to be erased */
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_erase());

        /* Retry nvs_flash_init */
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_init());
    }

    ret = wifim_wifi_on();
    if (ret != ESP_OK)
    {
        return;
    }

    wifi_config_t wifi_config;
    memset(&wifi_config, 0, sizeof(wifi_config_t));

    // Copy the SSID and password to the wifi_config structure
    strncpy((char *)wifi_config.sta.ssid, WIFI_SSID, sizeof(wifi_config.sta.ssid) - 1);
    wifi_config.sta.ssid[sizeof(wifi_config.sta.ssid) - 1] = '\0'; // Ensure null-terminated string

    strncpy((char *)wifi_config.sta.password, WIFI_PASSKEY, sizeof(wifi_config.sta.password) - 1);
    wifi_config.sta.password[sizeof(wifi_config.sta.password) - 1] = '\0'; // Ensure null-terminated string
    wifi_config.sta.channel = 0;
    wifi_config.sta.threshold.authmode = WIFI_AUTH_WPA_WPA2_PSK;
    ret = wifim_connect_ap(&wifi_config);
    if (ret == ESP_OK)
    {
        // Connection successful
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Connection successful");
    }
    else
    {
        // Connection failed, handle the error
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Connection failed %s", esp_err_to_name(ret));
    }

    return;
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error log:

```
I (0) cpu_start: App cpu up.
I (371) cpu_start: Pro cpu start user code
I (371) cpu_start: cpu freq: 160000000
...
assert failed: xQueueSemaphoreTake queue.c:1545 (( pxQueue ))
Setting breakpoint at 0x400819e9 and returning...
0x400819e9: panic_abort at /home/raghav/workspace/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/panic.c:402
```

I have tried different approaches to fix this error, but none of them have been successful. I would appreciate any assistance or guidance in resolving this issue.

esp-idf : v4.4
ESP32 module.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: There is a lot of code in your repository. Not many people here wish to go through it all, that's why we usually ask for a [*Minimal*, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). On topic: in my experience the FreeRTOS thread tools' assertions trigger most often when the resource they're manipulating (semaphore, queue, event group) has not been initialized. Probably not the immediate cause, but food for thought: variable `s_wifi_sem` is not guaranteed to be initialized to NULL here: `static SemaphoreHandle_t s_wifi_sem;` but you assume it to be, later.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was uninitialized QueueHandle_t xQueue, the assert comes from here: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/v4.4.5/components/freertos/queue.c#L1545